# Ionic 2 custom alert component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I would like to create a component that would work similarly as the native ionic 2 alert. The reason why I need a custom one is because the native alert component from Ionic, as far as I know, can't have a custom layout in case you need it. And in my case, I have a custom component I need to have inside its template.

Do you guys have any suggestion of how I could build it? Thanks

The alert should look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Take a modal instead. Make it as small as your imaged alert. Add all your wanted CSS.

Comment: As misha stated, you can get the same effect with a modal. I'm personally using [this one](https://github.com/ankosoftware/ng2-bootstrap-modal) and like it a lot (it comes with bootstrap-themed css, but you can override it).

Comment: I actually used Misha's suggestion and it worked the way I wanted :) thank you guys for your help

Comment: @misha130 do you know how can I handle parameters using modal? For example, I need to work in a way that when the user answer is "yes", the `theme` parameter contains what I need to render in my next page:
`presentModal($event, theme) {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    
    modal.present();
  }`

Comment: Check results on its dismissal modal.onDidDismiss(result=>...